# removing files with numerals in the beginning of the file name

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu

I'm working with Ubuntu recently and I have been asked to remove files with numerals at the beginning.

How do I remove ordinary files from current directory that have numerals at the first three characters?

Comment: Can you (1) show us a list of filenames, so we can see what data you're dealing with, (2) show us an example of what you want things converted to, (3) show us the code you've written that attempts to do this, and (4) show us the error or incorrect results you're getting with that code?

Comment: @femchi what happens when you use  command like this rm 132*?

Comment: I'm a newbie. there is not any code. I'm asking about the commands in the ubunto.

Comment: @Stranger it says no such a file or directory. I'm looking for a command deal with numbers from 0 to 9 is used in the first 3 places of the file name

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since nobody else bothered to post this,

```
rm [0-9][0-9][0-9]*
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all: **Be careful** when trying out such delete commands! Try running in a directory with test files or files that are backed up well.

You could try something like this from shell:

```
find . -regex './[0-9]{3}.*' -exec 'rm {}' \;
```

For debugging, try running it without the `rm`-command first, listing the files that will be deleted:

```
find . -regex './[0-9]{3}.*'
```

You may have to escape the curly braces - at least I had to in FreeBSD, using zsh-shell:

```
find . -regex './[0-9]\{3\}.*'
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Honestly I dont fully understand what you wrote because it seems as though you are more professional. I'm looking for more basic commands.

Comment: I found out this command. ls | egrep ^[0-9]{3}
it lists all the files started by 3 numbers. how can I remove them?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like

```
ls | egrep '^[0-9]{3}' | xargs rm
```

The `ls` lists all the files, the `egrep` filters the list so that it only contains filenames that start with three digits, and the `xargs` applies `rm` to each of the filenamess that `egrep` lets through.

Comment: How is this an improvement over `rm [0-9][0-9][0-9]*`? That will avoid parsing `ls` output (always a no-no) and cope with all file names correctly (even with embedded newlines) and also only involve one process.